# Make the close button visible in front of another element using CSS

Tags: css

I have a `table`, which I want to `hide` and `show` using **jQuery**. I want to add a **'close'** button to the top right.

But the close button always appears behind the table, so not able to visible

How can I make the close button appear in front of the table please (not above/to the side), and therefore available to be clicked on?

```
<style>
table
{
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    align: center;  
    text-align: center;
    color:#000000;
}

th,td
{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
}

#RCLPage
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;    
}

.close_box
{
    background-image:url('../tsTest2/images/close.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right top; 
    position:relative;
    z-index:101;
    //height:10px;
}

#CPSTab
{
    padding:10;
    width:20em; 
}

</style>


<div id="RCLPage">

    <div class="close_box"></div>

    <table id="CPSTab">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">The Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Item1</td><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Item2</td><td>5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Item3</td><td>3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give css like this

```
table{position:relative}
```

And for the Close Button

.`closeButton{ position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:999}`

You need to change the top and right value according to your requirements

http://jsfiddle.net/Lubuu/5/

Comment: cheers for that. I knew it would be something obvious that I had missed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `z-index` to the divs, with a positive number for the top div and negative for the div below

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/8cccm/)

Answer (score 1):

Set position:relative; for the close button container.
Set position:absolute for the button.
Set z-index for both (higher index for button).
Use: right: 0; top: 0; for button.

Answer (score 1):

Change the position of .close_box to 'absolute'

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9kXmq/

```
position:absolute;
```